# Is checkingout (co) a project on svn quicker when --quiet?

Tags: svn, repository, svn-repository

I have to checkout big projects with **svn** that take a while, so I'm just wondering if I set it to `--quiet` or `(-q)` so no messages are printed it would be quicker? Or does that have nothing to do with it?

Comment: Interesting set of answers.  I think the best idea is to measure it for yourself since it likely is going to depend on your environment.  On *nix you can use the `time` command and on Windows you can use Powershell's `Measure-Command` cmdlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're on a [VT100 terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) running at [BAUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baud) 300 or a [Teletype terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter), the `--quiet` option probably won't do much good. The terminal is probably displaying your files being checked out faster than they're being fetched from your server.

If you're using a version of Subversion older than 1.7 and you're on Windows, you may have issues with your anti-virus program scanning files as they're downloaded from Subversion. In older versions of Subversion, each file was downloaded twice: Once in your working directory, and once under the `.svn` directory as a base version you could use to do `svn diff` without bothering the server. Many Windows users complained about slow checkouts due to this issue. Updating to 1.7 or 1.8 will make Windows checkouts much faster.

---

You can try a *sparse* checkout where you only checkout the files you want. For example, we do release branching, and I find it easier to simply checkout the entire branch, then *update* only the projects I'm working on:

```
$ svn co --depth=immediates $RSVP/branches/5.2
```

This checks out the entire branch and all of the projects on that branch, but only the directories immediately under the branch. I get the project names, but I don't checkout anything under the projects. I now need to update my vibortz project:

```
$ svn up --set-depth=infinity 5.2/vibortz
```

Now, all the files in this one project are checked out. You could take this further.

```
$ svn up --set-depth=immediates 5.2/vibortz
A  docs
A  src
A  dependencies
```

I am not interested in the docs or dependencies, but I am interested in the buffer code in this project:

```
$ src up --set-depth=infinity 5.2/vibortz/src/buffer
A  src/buffer
A  ...
```

I have the entire project (Infact, the entire branch!) as a Subversion working directory, but I am only checkout out the files I'm actually interested. I can *update* additional directories as I see fit.

Most of the time, when I hear about a project taking so long to checkout, it's because compiled binaries are checked into the project (which is a no-no, but we won't get into here). You want to checkout the entire project, but you don't want the binaries. Again, sparse checkouts may work for you. Assuming BASH:

```
$ src co --depth=immediates $URL/trunk/vibortz
A  vibortz/binaries
A  vibortz/docs
A  vibortz/resources
A  vibortz/source
```

I just want resources and sources:

```
$ src up --set-depth=infinity vibortz/source vibortz/resources
```

If I want all the directories **except** binaries, I can do this:

```
$ shopt -s extglob    # Kornshell users don't have to do this...
$ cd vibortz
$ src up --depth=infinity !(binaries)
```

The `!(binaries)` excludes the directory `binaries` from my update. All directories **except** binaries will be updated and expanded.

Answer (score 2):

**Definitely YES**, using the standard output always will make slower any process. I've made dumps, loads, and of course checkouts and commits of 10-15GB of data recently, and always made it with -q, cause it reduces in a really high amount of time the process duration.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If the bottleneck is retrieving files from the server, then it won't make any difference. But if you have a slow console, then the limiting factor might be how fast it can spew lines to the terminal.

For a typical case, it's unlikely to make a difference, but there are corner cases when it would (SSH to remote machine over a slow link, and checkout there, to a local repo with lots of tiny files).